# Listening comprehension - "verstötten"?

Tags: listening-comprehension

While listening to the documentary https://youtu.be/eQsHgNZWxZs?t=102 at around time 1:42, the voice says "... doch das alte Indien verstöttert (?) mit atemberaubender Geschwindigkeit". For the life of me I can't figure out what that word is supposed to be. Thanks for any help.

Comment: "verstädtert" (urbanizes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> doch das alte Indien ***verstädtert*** mit atemberaubender Geschwindigkeit.

The verb »verstädtern« is derived from the noun »Verstädterung«. »Verstädterung« means »urbanization«, i.e. the trend of people to leave rural regions and to move into fast growing cities.

Comment: And notably, *verstädtern* carries a somewhat negative connotation that is not found in *urbanisieren*.